# How is entrySet linked to table in HashMap internals?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, internals

According to the `HashMap` doc on `entrySet()`:

> public Set> entrySet ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Returns a set containing all of the mappings in
>   this map. Each mapping is an instance of Map.Entry. **As the set is
>   backed by this map, changes in one will be reflected in the other.**
>
> Returns a set of the mappings.

But as I inspect the `HashMap` code I cannot understand how the field `entrySet` is linked to `table` or any other object.
I am trying to understand how `entrySet` is updated  when the `put()` method is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the implementation of `EntrySet`:

```
965  private final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
966      public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
967          return newEntryIterator();
968      }
969      public boolean contains(Object o) {
970          if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
971              return false;
972          Map.Entry<K,V> e = (Map.Entry<K,V>) o;
973          Entry<K,V> candidate = getEntry(e.getKey());
974          return candidate != null && candidate.equals(e);
975      }
976      public boolean remove(Object o) {
977          return removeMapping(o) != null;
978      }
979      public int size() {
980          return size;
981      }
982      public void clear() {
983          HashMap.this.clear();
984      }
985  }
```

Note that it's an *inner* class and has implicit access to all the state, and all the instance methods, of the enclosing `HashMap` instance. It implements its methods by calling the appropriate methods on the enclosing `HashMap`.

Comment: Obviously you see something I don't. I still look at the code for `put(key,value)` and there is there an invocation to `addNewEntry()` but I don't find where the `EntrySet` object is updated with the new entry, and in the code you posted, I also don't see how a new entry is linked to the `Set`. Also the `HashMapEntry` class constructor does nothing in this respect.

Comment: `EntrySet` is just a *view*. It has no data structure of its own, it just lets you observe and manipulate the enclosing instance's data structures through an API which is specific to the entry set.

Comment: I get that `EntrySet` can access any structure in `HashMap` class. I see the code, but can you please detail the linkage between this view and the internal objects mapped in `table`? Or are you saying that the assignment of a new `HashMapEntry` to `table[index]` is automatically reflected into the `entrySet` field. How?

Comment: Look at `contains` above. It will call `HashMap#getEntry`, which will look it up in `table`.

Comment: @MarioTopolnik OK, let me complete the explanation, for the sake of future users browsing this post. __ . The `EntrySet` class creates its own Iterator, which is of type `EntryIterator`, inner class of HashMap as well. This iterator `nextEntry()` method goes over the `table[]` advancing the index each time. This is the way you get each entry when you use the for loop `for( HashEntryMap<?,?> e: mymap.entrySet() )`

Comment: @ilomambo as per my understanding are you trying to say that when we call entrySet() method in a for-each loop , implicit call goes to iterator() method of EntrySet class ?

Answer (score 1):

`EntrySet` is a nested class within `HashMap` see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.EntrySet).